# C++ template specialization not working when comparing sizeof(type) == constant

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

uint32_t ReadInt() { return 0; }
uint64_t ReadLong() { return 0; }

template<class SizeType>
class MyType
{
  public:
    SizeType Field;
    MyType()
    {
        Field = sizeof(SizeType) == 8 ? ReadLong() : ReadInt();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyType<uint32_t> m;
    std::cout << m.Field;
}
```

I get a compiler warning because it looks like the the condition sizeof(MyType) == 4 is not being evaluated at compile time.

If it were we would have specialization and this wouldn't be a problem.

Anyway I could achieve this?

EDIT: What I *really* want to achieve is this:

```
        Field = ReadLong();
```

OR

```
        Field = ReadInt();
```

through template meta-programming. Can I do this without specializing the Read* functions? Given how powerful c++ templates I really feel like I'm missing some aha moment, because if I have to specialize Read* functions the rabbit hole continues to go deeper.

Comment: What warning are you receiving?

Comment: warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int64_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data

for the int specialization

Comment: where does the unsigned int come from all of the sudden though? Please post a complete working example. Might be how you call/instantiate, which causes the warning.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht I've added the example that compiles.

Comment: in that case the warning is most probably originating from your "Read*()" functions, as you do not have one defined for unsigned int and also you're not checking the type so you could call the appropriate function..

Comment: sizeof(SizeType) == 8 ? ReadLong() : ReadInt(); // constant expression in my mind.

Are you suggesting that the compiler is putting the condition as is, even though it could infer that this expression is a constant, so I would expect that the compiler could remove the condition entirely.

Comment: C++17 allows an elegant solutionnheee btw.  Constexpr if!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'int64_t' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data for the int specialization
> ```
>
> I get a compiler warning because it looks like the the condition sizeof(MyType) == 4 is not being evaluated at compile time.

No, it doesn't look like that at all. Whether the comparison is evaluated at compile time or not has no effect on the return type of the conditional expression.

If we simplify the example by removing the conditional and expand the template using the type that you used, we get this minimal reproduction:

```
uint32_t Field;
int64_t temp = ReadInt(); // temporary variable for exposition
Field = temp;
```

Clearly, the `int64_t` may contain a value that is much greater than can be represented by `int32_t`. If it does, then the correct value will be lost in conversion. The compiler warns about this possibility.

---

Why is the type of the conditional `int64_t` specifically you might ask. Well, the types of each subexpression is `int64_t` and `uint32_t` respectively, so the type must be one of those. The type of `Field` or the result of the comparison - even if evaluated at compile time - has no effect on which type is chosen. Instead, [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#integral_promotion) rules are used in this case.

---

> Anyway I could achieve this?

A template function should work:

```
template<class T>
T Read() {
    static_assert(false, "not implemented");
}

template<>
uint64_t Read<uint64_t>() {
    return ReadLong();
}

template<>
uint32_t Read<uint32_t>() {
    return ReadInt();
}

// ...
Field = Read<SizeType>();
```

Comment: I updated my example, I see what you're saying but why is the int64_t temp being an int64, shouldn't it be int32 ... I've told the compiler the data type of the field correctly.

Comment: @halivingston the data type of the field has no effect on the type of the conditional expression.

Comment: Yup, I get it. I'll edit my question again now, to basically say that I'd like that the expansion be Field = ReadInt(); or Field = ReadLong(); depending on the size of the SizeType. I wonder if I can do that without templatizing Read functions.

Comment: @halivingston why would you not want to templetize the Read functions?

Answer (score 1):

> I get a compiler warning because it looks like the the condition sizeof(MyType) == 4 is not being evaluated at compile time

Wrong, it is evaluated at compile-time, but the conditional operator still has the bigger result-type of the arguments.

To fix it, just add a cast:

```
Field = sizeof(SizeType) == 8 ? (SizeType)ReadLong() : ReadInt();
```

Another approach using overload-resolution:

```
long ReadData(long) { return ReadLong(); }
int ReadData(int) { return ReadInt(); }
Field = ReadData(SizeType());
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer if I don't find anything better, since it does suppress the warning and the correct things still happen. It feels like I should be able to do something cleaner.

Comment: Oh I just your other edit, hmmm that does look way cleaner. Is it all at compile-time? Ok I'm more hopeful now that this is the answer! Could you look at my edit to my question? I essentially want to do Field = ReadInt(); OR Field = ReadLong(); ... that said you do come very close.

Comment: A static_if would be a nice addition... though we don't have it. Something of interest if using gcc: [__builtin_choose_expr](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html)

Answer (score 0):

A conditional operator `?:` expression evaluates to a single type, which accommodates both possible internal-to-the-construct result types.

This happens even when it's evaluated at compile time.

The common type in your case is the largest of the two possible integer types.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose I want to achieve one or the other :

Field = ReadLong(); OR Field = ReadInt();

Any way to achieve that? Or do I need to specialize the Read functions? The rabbit hole goes deeper ...